# If I have a post with delete votes, I delete it myself, and then I undelete it, what will happen?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

*It is a hyphotetical idea. I have no intent to do this with any of my posts.*

---

Thus, consider the following events:

1. I make a post.
2. It is voted down.
3. It gets delete votes, *but not enough to be deleted*.
4. I delete it myself (consider if it is possible).
5. Then I undelete it. Because it was my own post deleted by me, I think also this is possible.

Is it possible?

What will happen to the delete votes what the question got in (3)?

Comment: Saad :-) It had been a so funny idea. In essence, the the delete votes will revive. The accepted answer of the dupe is unclear about the close votes in the case of questions (but it is not topic in this question), maybe wouldn't revive. My this question is a dupe.

Comment: I've just tested it, the self-deletion of this question [with ongoing vtc] didn't affect the close votes at all.

Comment: "An delete undelete sequence on a post by the post owner will invalidate only the owner's delete vote when the undeletion is made." - Seems to be pretty clear to me